# Is there a reason why Visual Studio puts every project output in a separate folder?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

By default, Visual Studio (2010 as well as 11 beta) builds every project in a solution to a separate folder. As a result, especially if the projects reference each other, they get copied around quite a lot during build `(CopyLocal = true)`:

```
-- solution has four projects: proj1, proj2, proj3 and proj4
-- building proj1 --
solution/proj1/bin/debug/proj1.dll
-- building proj2 (depends on proj1) --
solution/proj2/bin/debug/proj1.dll
solution/proj2/bin/debug/proj2.dll
-- building proj3 (depends on proj1) --
solution/proj3/bin/debug/proj1.dll
solution/proj3/bin/debug/proj3.dll
-- building proj4 (depends on proj2 and proj3) --
solution/proj4/bin/debug/proj1.dll
solution/proj4/bin/debug/proj2.dll
solution/proj4/bin/debug/proj3.dll
solution/proj4/bin/debug/proj4.dll
```

Since my current solution has 90 projects, from which the majority have at least a few references to one another (only 3 are actual executables), this is quite annoying and I've been wondering why, by default, Visual Studio does not just put every project output in the same folder but instead causes this horrendous redundancy. **I am aware that I can change the output folder and turn off the copying of referenced projects**, but I'd like to know if there is a reasoning behind the default behavior.

VS2005 does put everything in one folder by default (not sure about 2008), but did that have any actual disadvantages? Also, is there a way in VS10 (VS Addon maybe) to set the output folder for all projects to the same folder, as well as setting `CopyLocal = false` for each project reference?

Comment: It is a simple way to avoid file name collisions.  Not so much in the bin\Debug folder, definitely in the obj\Debug folder.

Comment: @HansPassant Good point, however the intermediate directory is independent from the actual output directory though. Even if the output directory is changed, the obj folder is still separate for each project, which does indeed make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I can think of is to separate the projects from each other, that is: if you change (and compile) one project it does not immediately break other projects that have not been updated properly to handle the change.

If everything is in one folder, the above scenario could cause unnecessary headaches (until you rebuild the whole solution).

Comment: Makes sense in theory, but say you have a dll and an exe, and you change the dll and run the exe, VS will alert you anyway that the solution is out of date and needs to be rebuilt. -- If you make a breaking change to the dll that isn't solved by a simple rebuild, you could theoretically work on modules independenly, however that's what interfaces and multiple solutions are for, since a change/rebuild of the exe in this case will still break everything.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of what happens when you run the program from outside of VS